# Rails - AJAX loading posts after submitting form in view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm having trouble with loading/populating the view with posts after submitting them through AJAX. The form itself is firing off and inserting the posts into the db. To be more clear, I need to load the posts after submission in the container below the post with JQuery slideDown. I have a normal post/shared post/commented post, partial render in the index action as well.

index.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="posts-feed-bg">
        <div id="post-index-form">
          <%= render 'posts/form' %>
        </div>
        <div class="post-textarea-bottom-border"></div>
        <div class="post-feed-container" id="posts-items">
          <% @posts.each do |post| %>
              <%= render partial: "posts/#{post.post_type}", locals: {post: post} %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

create.js.erb

```
<% if @post.save
      @post = Post.new
%>
    $('#post-index-form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts/form') %>');
    $('#post-text-area').val('');
    $('#post-items').html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts/post') %>');
    $('#post-items').slideDown(350);
    <% end %>
```

_post.html.erb

```
  <div class="post-container">
    <%= post.user.username %>
    <%= link_to post.title, post %>
    <%= post.body %>
    </div>
```

posts_controller.rb

```
def index
        following_ids = current_user.following_users.map(&:id)
        following_ids << current_user.id
        @posts = Post.where(user_id: following_ids).order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page])
        @users = User.same_background_focus_as(current_user).paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 5
        @post = Post.new
      end

 def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
    <%= simple_form_for(@post, id: '', multipart: true, remote: true) do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 emoji-picker-container post-textarea">
            <%= f.input :body_text, class: 'form-control', label: false, id: 'post-text-area' %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-outline-success' %>
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Server Log After Submitting Form

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-16 13:25:25 -0400
Processing by PostsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "post"=>{"body_text"=>"AJAX"}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (174.6ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("body_text", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["body_text", "AJAX"], ["user_id", 4], ["created_at", "2017-08-16 17:25:26.201583"], ["updated_at", "2017-08-16 17:25:26.201583"]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
  Rendering posts/create.js.erb
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
   (0.0ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (8.0ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (1273.9ms)
  Rendered posts/create.js.erb (1366.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2282ms (ActiveRecord: 178.1ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0x18937128>:0x1a9f6688>
Did you mean?  @post
               post_url):
    2:   <div class="media" style="padding-bottom: 2em;">
    3:     <img class="d-flex align-self-start mr-3 purple-rounded rounded" src="http://via.placeholder.com/60x60">
    4:     <div class="media-body post-user-name">
    5:       <h5><%= fa_icon 'user' %> <%= post.user.user_full_name %><%= link_to 'Delete', post_path(post), remote: true, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "You sure?"} if current_user == post.user %> </h5>
    6:       <p><%= post.body_text %> </p>
    7:     </div>
    8:   </div>

app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_posts__post_html_erb__960034244_222460104'
app/views/posts/create.js.erb:9:in `_app_views_posts_create_js_erb__1048995870_223328388'
```

New Error After making changes

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user_full_name' for nil:NilClass):
    2:   <div class="media" style="padding-bottom: 2em;">
    3:     <img class="d-flex align-self-start mr-3 purple-rounded rounded" src="http://via.placeholder.com/60x60">
    4:     <div class="media-body post-user-name">
    5:       <h5><%= fa_icon 'user' %> <%= post.user.user_full_name %><%= link_to 'Delete', post_path(post), remote: true, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "You sure?"} if current_user == post.user %> </h5>
    6:       <p><%= post.body_text %> </p>
    7:     </div>
    8:   </div>

app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_posts__post_html_erb__960034244_199162944'
app/views/posts/create.js.erb:9:in `_app_views_posts_create_js_erb__1048995870_199612656'
```

method for partial view changer
 post.rb

```
def post_type
    if post_id? && body_text?
      "quote_share"
    elsif post_id?
      "share"
    else
      "post"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you referenced the `id` **wrongly**. You have defined the `div` with `id` as `posts-items`, but in `create.js.erb` you are using `post-items` which is incorrect, so **JS** unable to find the selector with `post-items` which is the reason for the problem. Changing it to `posts-items` should fix your problem.

```
#create.js.erb
<% if @post.save
  @post = Post.new
%>
  $('#post-index-form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts/form') %>');
  $('#post-text-area').val('');
  $('#posts-items').html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts/post') %>');
  $('#posts-items').slideDown(350);
<% end %>
```

Also, this part of the code.

```
<% if @post.save
  @post = Post.new
%>
```

seems strange. I don't see any reason including it in `create.js.erb` unless there is a use. So remove it

```
#create.js.erb
$('#post-index-form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts/form') %>');
$('#post-text-area').val('');
$('#posts-items').html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts/post') %>');
$('#posts-items').slideDown(350);
```

**Update:**

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `post'
>   for #<#<Class:0x18937128>:0x1a9f6688>

Rails unable to find the `post` variable defined in `_post.html.erb` in this situation. Send it as a local variable in the partial. The final `create.js.erb` should like this

```
#create.js.erb
$('#post-index-form').html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts/form') %>');
$('#post-text-area').val('');
$('#posts-items').html('<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts/post', post: @post) %>');
$('#posts-items').slideDown(350);
```

Also, change `@post` to `Post.new` in the `form` so it won't conflict with `@post` in `create` action and always create a form for new instance

```
<%= simple_form_for(Post.new, id: '', multipart: true, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user_full_name' for
>   nil:NilClass)

This error is because that particular post doesn't have an associated user to it, so it errors out in this line `<%= post.user.user_full_name %>` To quickly resolve the error, use `try` method

```
<%= post.try(:user).user_full_name %>
```

Comment: Nothing is happening. The create method is working correctly. But, I have to refresh the page to see the post. The slideDown effect is not firing off, even though I made the changes that you requested.

Comment: @JohnnyC Can you update the question with the server logs that has fired?

Comment: I added <% if @-post.save @-post = Post.new %> to refresh the form. It went to the update action without it.

Comment: @JohnnyC Ok now I understood. But there are better ways handling that. First can you update the question with entire logs that appeared in the server?

Comment: @JohnnyC Well there is an error in fetching the partial that is why the slideDown isn't fired. I will update my answer.

Comment: It may be the way I am rendering the partial templates for the different post. I just realized that <%= render partial: "posts/#{post.post_type}", locals: {post: post} %>. I don't exactly know yet.

Comment: It no longer recognizes the method from my user class. I edited the post to show you that  ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user_full_name' for nil:NilClass)

Comment: I believe that I cannot use AJAX to render a multi-partial view link such as this one. I may need an if else or case statement of some sort to get the partial view types. <%= render partial: "posts/#{post.post_type}", locals: { post: post  %>